# Paging not displayed in Vue 2, Syncfusion Grid, class component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, syncfusion

I'm tying to add paging to a Syncfusion Grid in a class component in a Vue 2 project using TypeScript.  I am "Vue.use"-ing the GridPlugin in main.ts.

My understanding is that I must:

1. Import the Page class from ej2-vue-grids
2. Provide a service called grid that includes the Page class in an array
3. set allowPaging="true" and supply pageSettings

pageSettings is obviously applying because if I leave it out, it displays all rows.

Here is my stripped down code:

```
<template>
  <ejs-grid
    :data-source="data"
    :allow-paging="true"
    :page-settings="pageSettings"
  >
  </ejs-grid>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Provide, Vue } from "vue-property-decorator";
import { Page } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-grids";

@Component
export default class Organizations extends Vue {
  @Provide("grid") private grid = [Page];

  data = [
    { ID: 1, Name: "Widget 1" },
    { ID: 2, Name: "Widget 2" },
    { ID: 3, Name: "Widget 3" },
    { ID: 4, Name: "Widget 4" },
    { ID: 5, Name: "Widget 5" },
    { ID: 6, Name: "Widget 6" },
    { ID: 7, Name: "Widget 7" },
    { ID: 8, Name: "Widget 8" },
    { ID: 9, Name: "Widget 9" },
    { ID: 10, Name: "Widget 10" },
  ];
  pageSettings = { pageSize: 5 };
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [Syncfusion forum](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/149063/typescript-provide-to-inject-group-sort-etc-functionality-into-vue-component?reply=NfZalb).

The trick for class components to provide the Page is to use the options syntax within the `@Component` attribute:

```
@Component({
  provide: {
    grid: [Page]
  }
})
export default class Organizations extends Vue {
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on your requirement you need to apply paging to the grid. To achieve your requirement, we have prepared a sample by rendering paging in the grid.

```
<template>    
  <div>
<ejs-grid ref="grid" id="grid" :dataSource="data" height="100%" :allowPaging="true"
  :pageSettings="pageSettings" >
………………………………………..
</ejs-grid>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import { GridPlugin, Page } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-grids";
import { Browser } from "@syncfusion/ej2-base";
import { data } from "./datasource";

Vue.use(GridPlugin);

export default Vue.extend({
data: () => {
return {
  data: data,
  pageSettings: { pageSize: 5 },
};},
  methods: {},
  provide: {
 grid: [Page],
},});
</script>
```

Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-pare-erxy2?file=/src/App.vue